# Selecting peak areas from 2D matrices

Tags: matlab

Suppose we have an array like this :

```
A = peaks
A(A<0)=0   % Remove negative values to make things a bit more simple.
```

I would like to write a script that is able to select the whole volume of the peaks contained in  A.

For example, include all the values that surround a local maximum, until it hits values which are either 0 or a local minimum.

Below is a link to an answered question on a similar but more complicated topic.
[Find peak (regions) in 2D data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852754/find-peak-regions-in-2d-data)

I tried to use the method found on the answer to the question above, but I had little success for my example. I understand that in this answer, on the line:

```
im3=imextendedmax(im2,10);
```

, the value 10 acts as some kind of threshold.
If I leave the threshold value at 10, it only selects the upper part of the highest of the three peaks (kind of like selecting the snowy top of a mountain, but I would like the whole mountain).
I tried to lower it in order to select the entirety of the peaks, but this is the result I get:

[image]

[image]

In these results, 6 peaks are identified, but what I want is 3 separated peaks, as described in the picture below:

[image]

Hope this is clear enough.

Comment: What do you mean by 'The whole volume of the peaks contained in A'? Do you want to select points, of to calculate some kind of numerical integral? An image would be of great use here

Comment: When you say 'I tried to use the method found on the answer, but I had little success for my example.'. What did you do?

Comment: The code in the answer works for your case. Just change the value of the threshold in the call to `im3=imextendedmax(im2,0.2);` for the `peaks` matrix

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find peak (regions) in 2D data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852754/find-peak-regions-in-2d-data)

Comment: Hello @BillBokeey, I just edited the post to explain. Thank you for the suggestion, and for your time.

Comment: Have you tried with 0.2 by any chance?

Comment: @BillBokeey Yes, I did try several values including 0.2. In the case of 0.2 specifically, it selects the upper part of each peak, but I would like the whole "mountain", including the "foothills".

Comment: Changing the `tophat` also affects the output. Using `im2=imtophat(im,strel('disk',100));` starts to incorporate more of the foothills.

Comment: Hello @magnesium, i just tried what you suggested and it does improve it indeed. However, it is still not what I want, as I require all the data points. As I mentioned in the post, I need the selection to include everything from the top of the peak to the bottom, until the values are 0, or until it meets another peak (in which case, the local minima would be the border beteen the two peaks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting another separate answer to this question because it is a completely different approach, and it is complementary to the first one depending on the specific problem you are trying to solve

This approach is based on another definition of "Being inside a peak".

We will say that a point `(Xi,Yi)` belongs to the peak `#k` if, when doing a gradient ascent, the position `(Xi_,Yi_)` (Iterating during the ascent), converges to the position of the maximum of the peak #k.

This process can be visualized by using [`quiver`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html):

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(1:150,1:150);
[px,py]=gradient(im);
figure;quiver(X,Y,px,py,2.5);
```

[image: Quivers]

We will use the approach presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852754/find-peak-regions-in-2d-data) to get the indexes of the maximas:

```
% Image
Npts = 150;
im = peaks(Npts);
im(im<0)=0;

 % tophat transform
im2=imtophat(im,strel('disk',5));

% extended maximums
im3=imextendedmax(im2,0.2);

% Extract each blob
s=regionprops(im3,'Centroid','PixelIdxList');

xmaxes = zeros(numel(s),1);
ymaxes = zeros(numel(s),1);

for ii=1:numel(s)
    x=ceil(s(ii).Centroid);
    tmp=im*0;
    tmp(s(ii).PixelIdxList)=1;
    tmp2=tmp.*im2;

% The maximum amplitude and location

    [refV,b]=max(tmp2(:));
    [ymaxes(ii),xmaxes(ii)]=ind2sub(size(im),b);

end
```

And then do the gradient ascent:

```
% 2D gradient matrices
[px,py]=gradient(im);
Norm_p = sqrt(px.^2+py.^2);
px(Norm_p>0) = px(Norm_p>0)./Norm_p(Norm_p>0); % Normalized
py(Norm_p>0) = py(Norm_p>0)./Norm_p(Norm_p>0);

px_ = px; % Temp var to be modified during the loop
py_ = py; 

idx = find(im > 0);

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:Npts,1:Npts);
X_ = X;
Y_ = Y;

% Out of loop measure
eps = 1;

while eps > 1e-6

    % Follow the local normalized gradient direction
    X_(idx) = X_(idx) + px_(idx);
    Y_(idx) = Y_(idx) + py_(idx);
    
    % Clip back in the points that escape the grid
    X_(X_>Npts) = Npts;
    X_(X_<1) = 1;
    Y_(Y_>Npts) = Npts;
    Y_(Y_<1) = 1;
    
    % Interpolate gradient on the new positions
    px_(idx) = interp2(X,Y,px,X_(idx),Y_(idx));
    py_(idx) = interp2(X,Y,py,X_(idx),Y_(idx));
    
    
    % Out of loop cirterion, gets smaller as we reach maximas
    eps = max(sqrt(px_(idx).^2+py_(idx).^2));

end
```

Now we build a filter matrix, linking each point to the maximum it converged to:

```
% Build filter matrix
filtMtx = zeros(size(im));

for ii=1:numel(s)

    % Get all points that converged to the current max
    Dist2max = 100*ones(size(im)); % Initialize to high distance
    Dist2max(idx) = sqrt((X_(idx)-xmaxes(ii)).^2+(Y_(idx)-ymaxes(ii)).^2);
    
    filtMtx(Dist2max<1) = ii;
    
end
```

Finally, we can visualize the data:

```
% Output
figure,imagesc(im),axis image

ColSpcs = {'.r','.g','.b','.c','.m','.y','.k','.w'};

for ii=1:numel(s)
    
    hold on, plot(X(filtMtx == ii),Y(filtMtx == ii),ColSpcs{ii});
    hold on, text(xmaxes(ii)+10,ymaxes(ii),num2str(ii),'Color','white','FontSize',16);
    
end
```

[image: Output]

Note that the matrix `filtMtx` allows you to index each peak, `X(filtMtx == ii),Y(filtMtx == ii),im(filtMtx == ii)` are the `(X,Y,Z)` coordinates of all the points related to `peak ii`.

Please also note that this way doesn't guarantee you that all points will be linked to a maxima (for example, local minima have nil gradient and will not be linked to anything), but it guarantees that most of your points will.

Comment: This is pretty much perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There might be better (faster) approaches, but the following one seems to be working fine.

So the problem with what you want to do is that although it is possible to find the positions of the local maximas [like in the SO post you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852754/find-peak-regions-in-2d-data), the image must go through several transforms, which makes it impossible to get back the whole connected regions afterwards.

Let's quickly look at the code from the SO post, adapted to your problem:

```
% Image
im = peaks(150);
im(im<0)=0;

 % tophat transform
im2=imtophat(im,strel('disk',5));

% extended maximums
im3=imextendedmax(im2,10);

% Extract each blob
s=regionprops(im3,'Centroid','PixelIdxList');

figure,imagesc(im),axis image

for i=1:numel(s)
    x=ceil(s(i).Centroid);
    tmp=im*0;
    tmp(s(i).PixelIdxList)=1;
    tmp2=tmp.*im2;

% The maximum amplitude and location

    [refV,b]=max(tmp2(:));
    [x2,y2]=ind2sub(size(im),b);

% select the region around local max amplitude    
    tmp=bwselect(im2>refV*0.6,y2,x2,4);  

    [xi,yi]=find(tmp);
    hold on, plot(yi,xi,'r.')
    hold on, text(y2+10,x2,num2str(i),'Color','white','FontSize',16)    
end
```

Now there is still a set of parameters that you can act on: `tmp=bwselect(im2>refV*0.6,y2,x2,4);`

This selects from the `imtophat` transformed image, the patch of elements that are close from the point `(x2,y2)`, and for which the values are `>refV*0.6`, where `refV` is the value at the local maxima. By playing on the coefficient `0.6`, and applying `bwselect` to your initial image `im`, it is possible to achieve what you want, using an [optimization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization):

### The optimization problem

What we want here, is to select the maximum amount of pixels that are linked to each local maximum, in the sense of "All the points that are returned by the call to `bwselect` for a given local maxima, but are not belonging to another maxima"

### The scoring function

Like with all optimization algorithm we are gonna need a function that give a score to a set of `Tresholds` to be fed to the `bwselect` function `tmp=bwselect(im2>refV*T(i),y2,x2,4);`

My choice for this scoring function is as follows :

To exclude overlapping solutions (i.e. points belonging to several peaks at the same time), these will be scored +Infty (or 1e6 in my example)

For the others, we will count the number of pixels that don't belong to any patch. The optimal solution will be the solution where the peaks don't overlap but that cover the maximum amount of pixels, **i.e the solution with the smallest score**.

The code for the scoring function:

```
function score = Get_patches(s,im,T)

xi = cell(numel(s),1);
yi = cell(numel(s),1);

score = numel(im);

Left_Mtrx = ones(size(im));

for i=1:numel(s)

    tmp=im*0;
    tmp(s(i).PixelIdxList)=1;
    tmp2=tmp.*im;
    
    % The maximum amplitude and location
    
    [refV,b]=max(tmp2(:));
    [x2,y2]=ind2sub(size(im),b);
    
    % select the region around local max amplitude
    tmp=bwselect(im>refV*T(i),y2,x2,4);
    
    [xi{i},yi{i}]=find(tmp);
    bi = find(tmp);
    
    b_taken = find(~Left_Mtrx);
    
    if ~isempty(intersect(b_taken,bi))
        
        score = 1e6;
        break;
    
    else
        
        score = score - numel(bi);
        Left_Mtrx(bi) = 0;
        
    end

end

end
```

### The optimization

Now, what we need to do is to apply the particle swarm algorithm to your problem, using the previously mentioned scoring function:

```
% Image
im = peaks(150);
im(im<0)=0;

% tophat transform
im2=imtophat(im,strel('disk',5));

% extended maximums
im3=imextendedmax(im2,0.2);

% Extract each blob
s=regionprops(im3,'Centroid','PixelIdxList');

figure,imagesc(im),axis image

fun = @(T) Get_patches(s,im,T);

% Particle swarm optimization
% Initial positions of particles and best positions of particle
Pop_Size = 100;
Pos = rand(numel(s),Pop_Size);
Best_Pos = Pos;

% Get the best particule in the swarm
Best_Score = 1e6;
g = ones(3,1);

for jj=2:Pop_Size
    
    score = fun(Pos(:,jj));
    
    if score < Best_Score
        
       g = Pos(:,jj); 
       
       Best_Score = score;
       
    end
    
end

% Initialize particles speed
V = -1 + 2*rand(numel(s),Pop_Size);

% Number of iterations of the swarm
Nite = 100;
Count = 0;

% Particle swarm optimization parameters
w = 0.5;
Phi_p = 1;
Phi_g = 1;

% Initialize the scores
scores = zeros(1,Pop_Size);

while Count < Nite
    
    Count = Count +1;
    
    for ii = 1:Pop_Size
                    
        Rp = rand(numel(s),1); Rg = rand(numel(s),1);
        
        V(:,ii) = w*V(:,ii) + Phi_p*Rp.*(Best_Pos(:,ii)-Pos(:,ii)) + Phi_g*Rg.*(g-Pos(:,ii));
        
        Pos(:,ii) = Pos(:,ii) + V(:,ii);

        scores(ii) = fun(Pos(:,ii));
        
        if any(Pos(:,ii)<0) || any(Pos(:,ii)>1)
            
           scores(ii) = 1e6; 
            
        end
        
        BP_score = fun(Best_Pos(:,ii));
        
        if scores(ii) < BP_score
            
            Best_Pos(:,ii) = Pos(:,ii);
            
            if scores(ii) < Best_Score
                
               g =  Pos(:,ii);
               
               Best_Score = scores(ii);
                
            end
            
        end

    end

end


% Get better (minimum) score
idx_Best = find(scores == min(scores));

Best_tresholds =  Pos(:,idx_Best(1));

for i=1:numel(s)
    
    tmp=im*0;
    tmp(s(i).PixelIdxList)=1;
    tmp2=tmp.*im;
    
    % The maximum amplitude and location
    
    [refV,b]=max(tmp2(:));
    [x2,y2]=ind2sub(size(im),b);
    
    % select the region around local max amplitude
    tmp=bwselect(im>refV*Best_tresholds(i),y2,x2,4);
    
    [xi,yi]=find(tmp);
    
    hold on, plot(yi,xi,'r.')
    hold on, text(y2+10,x2,num2str(i),'Color','white','FontSize',16)
    
    
end
```

### Output

[image]

### If you want to extract the values in your original array corresponding to each region:

```
[sz1,sz2] = size(im);
Output_Matrices = zeros(sz1,sz2,numel(s));

for i=1:numel(s)
    
    tmp=im*0;
    tmp(s(i).PixelIdxList)=1;
    tmp2=tmp.*im;
    
    % The maximum amplitude and location
    
    [refV,b]=max(tmp2(:));
    [x2,y2]=ind2sub(size(im),b);
    
    % select the region around local max amplitude
    tmp=bwselect(im>refV*Best_tresholds(i),y2,x2,4);
    
    [xi,yi]=find(tmp);
    
    hold on, plot(yi,xi,'r.')
    hold on, text(y2+10,x2,num2str(i),'Color','white','FontSize',16)
    
    % Your output matrix i-th slice holds the values for the i_th peak
    Output_Matrices(xi,yi,i) = im(xi,yi); 


end
```

Comment: That looks very impressive. The thing is, I'm not quite sure if it solves my problem. I don't use the data as an image, I just use the array itself, in order to look at the position of each of the peaks and calculate their respective volumes. I normally use a surf plot just to visualize my array, and then I manually delete all the data points except for one of the peaks ,  run a script that does my calculations on the points that are left, and then repeat the same for every peak. Therefore, maybe looking at the problem from an image analysis perspective might not be the most effective method.

Comment: I added the extraction procedure. It this what you wanted?

Comment: I would like to have every single data point that is not 0 selected. If this code could be updated to do this, that would be great.

Comment: @Aristarchos Because you are in 3D and the gradients might not be the same in all directions, It would not make too much sense. For example, take the example of a [saddle (2nd image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point). How do you decide which point goes where? If you want every point to belong to a peak, you will have to define, in a very precise way, what it means to be inside a peak :)

Comment: I see, it might be a bit more complicated that I thought. But if there are no such saddle points, and there is just a curve of local minima separating the peaks (as in, between any two peaks in the example above), would it be possible to assign those points in both, or none of the peaks? (hope that makes sense)

Comment: The problem is not with how to sort the local minimas, it is about what to do with the points that are lower than at least one local minima (i.e. the points in light blue on my last output). It is difficult to find a definition of "Being inside a peak" for these points. One could for example argue that all these points belong to the biggest peak. Or to the closest maximum. Or an argument with the gradients, etc.. All of these kinda make sense, but you have to choose a definition according to what your actual usecase is

Comment: For example, take an array that has value 1 everywhere except for two separate parabolic peaks. What do you do with the "Floor of 1s"?

Comment: Well, @Aristarchos, speaking about gradients has given me an idea, I might come up with something else in the near future